# Does a Paladin with Aura of Protection effectively get twice the Charisma save modifer?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, saving-throw

The question is actually rather straightforward and many people seem to be confused about it:

**When a 6th or higher level paladin that has Aura of Protection rolls a Charisma save, does he essentially add his Charisma modifier twice in that kind of roll?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Effectively, yes.

The source of confusion is likely a gut reaction against the idea of stacking the same bonus with itself. However, that's not what's happening here. The paladin is not getting their Charisma modifier *twice*: they're getting their Charisma modifier once, and also getting a different bonus that *just so happens* to often (but not always) be the same number as their Charisma modifier:

> the creature gains **a bonus to the saving throw equal to** your Charisma modifier (with a minimum bonus of +1)

(emphasis mine)

Two separate bonuses, one derived from the other, and the game doesn't care about that derivation: they're still different and nothing prevents them from stacking. The wording appears to be designed specifically to make the Aura work in exactly this way.

Answer (score 10):

My first reaction would be to say no... but after reading the text of Aura of Protection, indeed that would be the case: **yes, you add your Charisma modifier twice to the die roll on Charisma saving throws**. The first time you add it, its in the form of an ability modifier, and the second is a bonus modifier.

What might get people confused is that the rules disallow adding your proficiency bonus more than once to a roll, but in this case, you are not adding proficiency twice, but your Charisma modifier.