# How does Aura of Protection work with multiple paladins?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin

If multiple paladins are present, do members of their party receive both of their charisma modifiers on top of saving throws?

For example: Two paladins, one with a CHA score of 16, one with 18, are near a squishy wizard forced to make a CON save. Would that wizard add 7 to the result, or only one of the modifiers?

As far as I can tell, the wording in the PHB wouldn't prevent this, nor is it brought up in the errata- but it would be helpful to know of any materials or sage advice concerning this scenario.

Comment: Related:[Does a Paladin with Aura of Protection effectively get twice the Charisma save modifer?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/54019/does-a-paladin-with-aura-of-protection-effectively-get-twice-the-charisma-save-m)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## The auras' benefits don't stack.

Jeremy Crawford, official rules designer for 5e, released [errata for the DMG that addresses this and similar situations](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMG-Errata.pdf):

> ***Combining Game Effects (p. 252).*** This is a new subsection at the end of the “Combat” section:
>
> > Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the “Combining Magical Effects” section of chapter 10 in the *Player’s Handbook*.

This clarifies that features of the same name don't stack with themselves - so a creature can only benefit from one Aura of Protection at a time (presumably the most potent one would be from the paladin with the highest Charisma mod).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the 2 auras will stack. There is a rule to prevent the proficiency bonus from being stacked on a roll, and there is a rule that says you can't benefit from 2 of the same spell simultaneously, but these are the only rules that restrict bonus stacking.

Additionally, Jeremy Crawford, lead designer of D&D 5e, [has confirmed](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/07/20/paladins-and-aura-of-protection/) that you can benefit from multiple Auras of Protection. [Twice.](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/18/does-paladins-aura-of-protection-stack/)

Comment: Were these statements before or after the DMG errata that seems to contradict these tweets?

Comment: @DerekStucki I'm wondering that too, the errata is pretty clear that class features, abilities, and spells don't stack. http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMG-Errata.pdf
He mentions some errata in his tweet, but it seems like he's just disregarding what it says if he is indeed talking about the same errata.

Comment: The difficult thing about picking an answer here is determining whether sage advice has any weight compared to errata. It would be helpful if Jeremy had ever addressed the errata itself, but as it stands, it seems official errata trumps designers' clarifications.

Comment: @Psyntax Yeah, I was planning to bounty the other answer if you didn't accept it, I'm pretty sure it's the right one.

Comment: It should be noted that Crawford has rescinded Sage Advice before, usually upon further consideration of the matter. In some cases it is addressed in a Sage Advice article rather than a tweet, but it may be that JC realized that in this case the RAW doesn't actually work with the RAI. Thus the errata which addresses the problem as well as several others.

Comment: As suggested above, Crawford has confirmed that the errata is correct, and the older tweet is now wrong: ["The errata is more recent than that old tweet."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1047626358057185280)