# Does a Wall of Force inhibit a Paladin's Aura of Protection?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, paladin, aura

If an enemy caster placed a *Wall of Force* between a Paladin and their ally, is the Paladin's Aura of Protection inhibited while the *Wall of Force* is up?

The description for *Wall of Force* says that "Nothing can physically pass through the wall."  If that doesn't include the Aura, is there anything that would inhibit it (lead, stone, etc)?

Comment: Related: ["Do auras require line of effect"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121354/do-auras-require-line-of-effect)

Comment: Related: "[Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59734)" and "[How does Wall of Force grant cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132265)" and "[Do Gaze Effects work through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132122)"

Answer (score 7):

### No

(But there is no official rule about auras; so it's up to the DM.)

[Aura of Protection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin) Says:

> you or a friendly creature within 10 feet...
>
> ...You must be conscious to grant this bonus.

There are no other specifications.  So technically even if you are in jail cells blocked by stone walls, or walls of force you would still fulfill the requirement of being within 10' (assuming you are conscious)

[Wall of Force](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force)  Does say:

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall

However nothing it the Aura of Protections description suggests that it is a physical manifestation. So barriers don't apply.  Only Range and consciousness.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to spell out exactly what why *wall of force* *doesn't* stop the aura

Comment: Why is it up to the DM?

Comment: @NautArch because everything is

Comment: Hooray!  This is the first answer I have given, to which the format was not edited/corrected by someone else!   Thanks guys!