# Can I keep a hollyphant in a gem necklace with the Imprisonment spell and use its Aura of Invulnerability trait to be immune to lower-level spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, aura

The description of the [hollyphant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hollyphant)'s Aura of Invulnerability trait says:

> An invisible aura forms a 10-foot-radius sphere around the hollyphant
> for as long as it lives. Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from
> outside the barrier can't affect creatures or objects within it, even
> if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot. Such a spell can
> target creatures and objects within the barrier, but the spell has no
> effect on them. Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded
> from the areas affected by such spells. The hollyphant can use an
> action to suppress this trait until its concentration ends (as if
> concentrating on a spell).

The description of the [*Sequester*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sequester) spell says, in part:

> If the target is a creature, it falls into a state of suspended
> animation. Time ceases to flow for it, and it doesn't grow older.

The description of the [*Imprisonment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/imprisonment) spell's Minimus Containment option says:

> The target shrinks to a height of 1 inch and is imprisoned inside a
> gemstone or similar object. Light can pass through the gemstone
> normally (allowing the target to see out and other creatures to see
> in), but nothing else can pass through, even by means of teleportation
> or planar travel. The gemstone can't be cut or broken while the spell
> remains in effect.

Basically I want a hollyphant in a gem necklace, so I can be immune to spells of 5th level and lower.

Does this RAW/RAI legally work?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I've attempted to summarize the question in the title; please check to make sure I've accurately summarized your question.

Comment: (I'm not really sure how the *sequester* spell is even relevant to what you want to do, other than keeping the hollyphant from dying of old age? I don't know how long they live, or whether they age in the first place. Or is the goal of *sequester* to prevent the hollyphant from using an action to suppress the Aura of Invulnerability trait?)

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, as the same question has been asked before about paladin auras.

Answer (score 6):

The aura will not be projected out of the gem, because *Imprisonment* spell text quite explicitly says

> nothing else can pass through

This is a rule specific to being *imprisoned* in this particular way, so it takes precedence over hollyphant generally projecting its aura while alive. [Here is a rules link](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral) and here is [a QA](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135076/11358) about this rule.

[This QA](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121354/11358) discusses if auras should penetrate total cover in general, but again the spells explicit feature will override any more general rule, or lack of a rule, about this.

---

Also, if a DM wishes to rule otherwise, they should consider this: If it could, there are a bunch of other auras, not to mention gaze effects and other similar things, which might "leak" too, depending on exact wording of the feature. That would quickly make things rather silly.